# Http1 / Netty Question : Do we see http request and content in the same channel read

Tags: netty, http-1.1

We have a bare-bones Netty http (1.1) proxy in our architecture. I would like to know whether the channel handlers in Netty see a http request and content in the same channelRead in a channelHandler. How is this typically configured?